# Good books or tutorial fo Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Where Can I find good tutorials or books for Windows Phone 8.
Please suggest your experience and good resources.

Comment: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8

Comment: This is off topic here check out our FAQ section but SE network has a site for [Windows phone](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/) which is in beta yet. But you can ask it there, but don't forget to read their FAQ section before posting it there.

Comment: @avirk I read faq `Developing/programming for Windows Phone` questions are off topic

Comment: @InderKumarRathore so you are looking for a programming/developing tutorial for Windows phone?

Comment: Generally, these types of questions are offtopic on all stackexchange sites because it does not fit a Q&A model. There is no single 'solution'. It is a list question

Comment: Do you need information about how to use WP8 or how to write code for WP8?

Comment: @sannySin Write code for WP8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk
Then search MSDN for any available info